# Codeigniter cannot connect to database

Tags: database, macos, codeigniter, xampp, localhost

What should I put for `codeigniter` database.php hostname?

I try putting "localhost","localhost:8080" but I cannot connect.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root@localhost',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'hnc-cms',
```

Comment: For a question that's as specific as this, you need to provide a lot of information otherwise it's impossible to even guess how to help... Server information, at the very minimum, is needed here.

Comment: i am trying to connect my localhost.

Comment: Try `root` as the DB username (without the `@localhost` part). The location part of the username is determined by the server depending on where you're connecting from

Comment: also, what kind of database is it? mysql? You don't seem to be specifying (at least you're not showing it) the database driver with the `dbdriver` element

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The hostname is localhost.
But you have to set base url in config.php
Like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/yourpathname/';
```

Comment: without setting this and the database config, I can redirect to codeigniter welcome page.

Comment: oh i thought you cannot connect the localhost

Answer (score 0):

turns out I found the solution and I not sure whats the issue that causes this.
When I uses window environment, I can put localhost as my hostname but when I changed to Mac, I need to specify the port number for mysql.
As for my case is localhost:3306, still curious why it happen.